# Oracle function to distinct NULL values based on other column

Tags: sql, oracle, function, select, null

I am looking for the simplest solution that will resolve following problem.
I have a table:

```
Column1           Column2
-------           -------
A                 11
A                 NULL
B                 12
B                 14
B                 NULL
C                 NULL
```

I would like to query(Select) this table to achive only NULL value when this is the only value for distinct value of column1. When there is at least one non null value with column1 it is important to bypass then null values for them. Desired outcome:

```
Column1           Column2
-------           -------
A                 11
B                 12
B                 14
C                 NULL
```

I was trying with COALESCE, NULLIF.. etc and had no results. I would like to achieve this with simplest solution. I am joining then Column2 with column in other table but for NULL I hope left join could be appropriate .

I am very grateful for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT column1, column2 
  FROM dummy t1
 WHERE column2 IS NOT NULL 
       OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT '' 
                        FROM dummy t2 
                       WHERE t1.column1 = t2.column1 
                         AND column2 IS NOT NULL)
```

Keeps all rows for which column2 either not NULL or are NULL and are the only within in a group.

Answer (score 0):

Should work like this ( there might be a more perfomant way though )

```
select column1, column2 
  from table where column2 is not null
union
( select column1, column2 
  from table 
  where column2 is null
    and column1 not in ( select column1
                           from table
                          where column2 is not null 
                          group by column1)
)
```

The first select above the union gets all rows without `null` values, then the second one simply adds all rows with `null` values in column2, but not the ones you had allready an the first one. `group by` not necessary for the result, but might clearify the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a left join, first get the values you need from the table and then join it to itself.

Shown here as a CTE for clarity.

```
WITH Col1Values AS
(
   SELECT DISTINCT Column1           
   FROM Table
)
SELECT Col1Values.Column1, T2.Column2
FROM Col1Values 
LEFT JOIN Table T2 ON Col1Values.Column1 = T2.Column1
```

or with a sub-query

```
SELECT T1.Column1, T2.Column2
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT Column1           
   FROM Table
) T1
LEFT JOIN Table T2 ON T1.Column1 = T2.Column1
```

Answer (score 0):

Inner query: Use analytic function to compute how many non-null C2 values each C1 has
Outer query: filter for rows with non-null C2 or count-distinct-C2=0

```
SELECT C1, C2
FROM (
        SELECT C1, C2, COUNT(C2) OVER (PARTITION BY C1) C2_COUNT
        FROM TABLE
    ) 
WHERE C2 IS NOT NULL OR C2_COUNT = 0;
```

Join version of same solution (no analytic functions)

```
SELECT  C1, C2 
FROM    TABLE 
        NATURAL INNER JOIN
        (SELECT C1, COUNT(C2) C2_COUNT 
         FROM TABLE GROUP BY C1)
WHERE   C2 IS NOT NULL OR C2_COUNT = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 select c1, c2 from t where c2 in (select distinct c2 from t where c2 is not null);
```